# How to fit the an image in to a collectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently I have the below image:
[image]

I would like to insert a picture inside the container. 
but when I run this code

```
//MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}
//make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    //get  a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AppIconViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.ImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "page-01")

    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    return cell
}
```

the result is this:
[image]

my understanding is that the image is larger than the frame causing the frame to expand.

How can I set an image inside so that the it fit within the box in the first image?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

For that, you would need to add explicit **height** and **width** constraint. I assume you have a proper size to return in the method `sizeForItemAt`.

Lastly, don't forget to set `cell`'s or `ImageView`'s `clipsToBounds` to `true`.

Comment: I manage to fix this my going into storyboard and fix the height and width constraint for the image. and making sure that it was less than the size of the content view inside the cell. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You want 3 collection view cells in each row and the above image will fit in each cell. You need to implement the **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** delegate methods to set the collection view cell.

I am assuming that the cell will square and there is a gap of 10px between each cell and each line (so minimum line spacing and inter-item spacing will be 10)

```
    let cellGap = 10
    let leftGapToScreen = 10
    let rightGapToScreen = 10
    let minLineSpacing = 10
    let minInterItemSpacing = 10

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let availableWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - (2 * cellGap) - 
    leftGapToScreen - rightGapToScreen
    let cellWidth = availableWidth / 3
    let cellHeight = cellWidth
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftGapToScreen, bottom: 0, right: rightGapToScreen)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return minLineSpacing
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return minInterItemSpacing
}
```

Now, make a custom collectionViewCell and put an imageView in it. Use auto-layout so that the image wholely fits inside the super view. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is an easier question. So, in the future I would suggest doing a few searches because that way you will learn the basics faster.

```
           cell.ImageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "page-01")
            cell.ImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

This is the basic rundown. When you access the .contentMode property on your image view you might want to experiment with the available options to see which one you like best.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode